# How do I make Debian 9 detect network hardware?

Tags: debian, networking, broadcom

While programming, without big deals, the wifi stoped working. I tryed to unload and load the b43 drivers my wifi uses, but didn't work, tired, I decided to do a fresh install of debian 9.4.
I did so, I did re-install b43 and enable it, but I just realize the problem is no network adapter is recognise. 
The result of lspci is as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b) 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) 
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04) 
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI 0 (rev 04) 
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04) 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4) 
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4) 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04) 
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01) 
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12) 
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

The laptop stopped working suddenly so I don't believe it's due to hardware problems.
How can I make debian detect my wi-fi card?

Comment: Your wifi card isn't listed , run `update-pciids` then  check it with `lspci`.

Comment: Does `dmesg` show any messages regarding the `b43` driver? Does `modprobe b43` give any errors? That might give us some more clues to look at. Also, make sure that [the firmware is installed](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx#b43).

Comment: What makes you think that the hardware is indestructible? The connectors for the wifi card can be bad over time, mechanical, chemical reasons....

Answer (score 1):

Does the laptop have a physical RF-killswitch? Typically such a switch would disable the WiFi and bluetooth transmitters by virtually "unplugging" them.

Comment: @Roberto P. Romero, To add to this answer, you may need to reboot after installing your drivers and verifying that any hardware switches are on to reinitialize your kernel and devices.